Is it possible to use the question 'Where are you from?' in everyday situations?
This question 'Where are you from?' can be used in daily conversations to ask where someone was before they came to me?
For example: 'Where are you from?' The answer: 'I'm from school, mom, there was athletics today.' Or 'I was at work, sorry I didn’t let you know earlier.'

Where have you just come from? or Where were you? both   ask where the person was before coming there.  The answer might be "school" or "the train station" or "football practice" or anything that seems like a reasonable thing to say in response to a person wants to know where you were and what you were doing there.  Where are you from? wants to know your country or home town.

"Where are you from?" is grammatically correct, but it usually refers to the place or country somebody was born/grew up, or if they're travelling, the place they normally live.

"Where are you from, John?" "Oh, I grew up near New York in the USA."

The simplest change is to add coming: "Where are you coming from?" This isn't too polite or too rude. There are a few other ways you'd ask that question:

Direct/rude: "Where were you?" - You'd say this if somebody is late and you're upset. In your examples, the answerer apologizes, so this might be the best translation.
Indirect/polite: "What have you been doing this morning/afternoon?" - This is more polite because it's less direct. Someone might respond to this with "Nothing much, you?" similar to "What's up?" or "How's it going?"


OP's query:

Where are you from?'
The answer: 'I'm from school, mom, there was athletics today.' Or 'I was at work, sorry I didn’t let you know earlier.'

The question:
Where are you from?"
is used to ask about someone's origin, hometown or native place.
If you have to get these answers:
I'm from school, mom, there was athletics today.' Or 'I was at work, sorry I didn’t let you know earlier.'
The questions would be
1."Where have you been?" is  the more common and  correct question to ask about someone's recent whereabouts or activities.
2."What have you been doing?"
or
3."Where did you go?"
